# How do I create CSS code to override existing theme breakpoints in Custom CC?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I used Google Chrome to inspect the cart of my WooCommerce website and I noticed that the theme I'm currently using has the following CSS code set:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)

.woocommerce-cart table.cart td.actions .coupon {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
```

How do I use Custom CSS to change the breakpoints as follows:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 535px)

.woocommerce-cart table.cart td.actions .coupon {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
```

Comment: So basically you have to extend the parent theme style.css file with the child theme style.css file. So you can paste your css to the style.css located in your child theme folder which should apply your css to the screen width of 535px. Most of the themes also have a custom css section in their theme options. You can also use some plugins to add some custom css.


Note: You shouldn't change code in your parent theme, because this code will get lost after next theme update.

Comment: Thank you @soDub I tried but it didn't work. I had to change the code slightly.

This seemed to do the trick.


`@media only screen and (max-width: 535px){
.woocommerce-cart table.cart td.actions .coupon {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use one of these method to adjust or override the css:

- From Appearance >> Customize >> Additional CSS , then add the new css code.
- Open the child theme style.css file and change the css.